# Ionic Angular Capacitor Android NodeJS - API connection fail

Tags: android, node.js, angular, ionic-framework

- So I have my API deployed to server and tested with Postman and it works. API is served by NodeJS
- the API connection from the Ionic Angular App is set to the server IP.
- The persmission is set in AndroidManifest.xml

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
> ```

- capacitor.config.json added

> ```
> "server": {
>     "allowNavigation": [
>       "xx.xx.xxx.xxx"
>     ]
>   },
> ```

-config.xml

> `<access origin="*" />`

install the debug.apk on my mobile device and it does not connect to the api on the server. Run it on Android Studio Emulator also does not work. How do I debug this as there are no errors showing up anywhere, it just simply does not return any data from the API calls. Where do I go from here?

Comment: Check the logcat for errors

Comment: logcat does not provide any useful information at all for me to use until I added

android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

in AndroidManifest.xml

from there it shows up CORS issue. I was able to solve it to allow origin from http//:localhost from my nodejs server. Wondering why Postman works earlier without having the allow origin set.....